# troubles with using admob, but i dont know why

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have got some troubles with admob..

i import this for my project: adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\libproject\google-play-services_lib

and there is example and i use it but nothing work :( 
adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140702\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\samples\admob
i change d_unit_id with mine. But i stil get eror

```
01-03 06:52:49.312: W/Ads(16453): Failed to load ad: 3
01-03 06:53:49.382: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(16453): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 5089000 but found 4325012
01-03 06:53:49.382: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(16453): GooglePlayServices not available due to error 2
01-03 06:53:49.398: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(16453): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 5089000 but found 4325012
01-03 06:53:49.398: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(16453): GooglePlayServices not available due to error 2
```

and thet eror
    01-03 06:52:49.312: W/Ads(16453): Failed to load ad: 3

I change compile in jdk 1.7 and android to 4.4W both.
and i log https://apps.admob.com and copy from there ad_unit_id and there msut be working, but i always get aror and adwartismant dont work on examples :(

there is manifest file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.google.android.gms.samples.ads"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="9"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <!-- Used to request banner and interstitial ads. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <!-- Used to avoid sending an ad request if there is no connectivity. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.samples.ads.GoogleAdsSampleActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".BannerXmlActivity"
            android:label="@string/banner_in_xml"/>
        <activity android:name=".BannerCodeActivity"
            android:label="@string/banner_in_code"/>
        <activity android:name=".InterstitialActivity"
            android:label="@string/interstitial"/>
        <!-- Activity required to show ad overlays. -->
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"/>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and there is banner code activity:

```
package com.google.android.gms.samples.ads;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdSize;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

/**
 * Example of including a Google banner ad in code and listening for ad events.
 */
public class BannerCodeActivity extends Activity {
    private AdView mAdView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_banner_code_ad_listener);

        mAdView = new AdView(this);
        mAdView.setAdUnitId(getResources().getString(R.string.ad_unit_id));
        mAdView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);
        mAdView.setAdListener(new ToastAdListener(this));
        RelativeLayout layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layout.addView(mAdView, params);
        mAdView.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        mAdView.pause();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mAdView.resume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        mAdView.destroy();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

and my xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</RelativeLayout>
```

My project is organized: http://prntscr.com/4b7c5f

i get in note 3 this eror:

```
08-09 22:20:04.245: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(22599): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
08-09 22:20:04.275: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(22599): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
08-09 22:20:04.285: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(22599): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
08-09 22:20:04.295: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(22599): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
08-09 22:20:04.355: W/Ads(22599): There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 2
08-09 22:20:04.355: I/Ads(22599): Scheduling ad refresh 60000 milliseconds from now.
08-09 22:20:04.355: W/Ads(22599): Failed to load ad: 2
```

Comment: Did you use an emulator with google API? Paste the layout, the activity and your manifest code.

Comment: no my phone with os 2.3.6

Comment: Error is alredy tell you have to change value of google play services version code  5089000 instead of 4325013 in AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: sounds like you need to update Googleplay services through the SDK manager

Comment: i cant update :( because i install on the fridy

Comment: Try using your phone as the emulator and check out it works.... The code looks fine... The problem is the Google play version required is greater than that in your emulator....

Comment: do any of the api's need updating, the only differnece to mine in the code is my min SDK is 14. also look in the sdk manager and install the latest version of the api - if that is installed - uninstall it and try installing the version before. What version do you currently have installed?

Comment: Update your phones Google play services from Google play store ..... your phones Google play services are out dated.....

Comment: i use on note 3 i get this error 08-09 22:18:03.965: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(22599): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
08-09 22:18:03.965: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(22599): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
08-09 22:18:04.035: W/Ads(22599): There was a problem getting an ad response. ErrorCode: 2

Comment: Check in values>Strings file if ad_unit_id is assigned a value ..... ad_unit_id should be assigned your ad mob id

Comment: Update play services and let know if the error occurs.... paste logs if it does....